Where can I view/manage the new SQL server 2022 server roles?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#permissions-of-new-fixed-server-roles-in-sql-server-2022
Under the security, server roles, or under the login's roles I can see the usual roles like sysadmin, etc. Where can I view/manage the new SQL server 2022 sever roles as shown in the above article?
Example: MS_DatabaseConnector

I daily use SSMS 19.1 and it shows in Security> Server Roles as a standart like older roles.

Also you could assign users to new roles as a standart.

My server version is 16.0.1000.6
If your SSMS is older that might cause to hide the new roles.

ssms 20.2 is the current version
